# Instruments chart for iphone

Tags: iphone

i have a doubt ..i clicked on leaks and then i can see graph now **should i run application to check memory leak or it will do on its own**??
and the moment my apps start after 3 secs i can see blur bar of height 0.5 that keep going?? so what should i do??
is that leak permanent (cause blue bar is static ?? but my app is running good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You check for memory leaks. At that time your app runs then only instrument can check for memory leaks. Click on the leaks and press record. It will run your app automatically if its selected in the apps drop down list in the instrument. If there will a leak then you will see a red spike in the leak chart. 
Presence of leak does not mean your app will crash. It will crash only when it will be running out of memory due to leaking memory repeatedly.

Comment: yes i can see some red spikes but there is blue one as well below red and that is running continuously and is my app really running?? how about button press event ??? who will call them to see memory leak???/

Comment: If you are running instrument using simulator then if you can see your app running in the simulator or if you are using device then it will be running in the device. You will have press the button then only instrument will check leaks on that event.

Comment: Also the blue chart is the total memory allocated by your app not the leaks.

Comment: but my apss is running very slow on my iphone  using instruments i dont know why but ther is very less red line